# Why my autocompletebox does not display any data?

Tags: silverlight

I have a silverlight autocompletebox, am adding the ItemsSource in the codebehind.cs , also set the valuemember path as well, it does not display any data.

here is the code,

```
<sdk:AutoCompleteBox   Margin="105,2,40,0" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ValueMemberPath="Code" FilterMode="Contains" IsTextCompletionEnabled="True" x:Name="txtcode"  Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Top" TabIndex="1" TabNavigation="Local" >
                            <sdk:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock  />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </sdk:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </sdk:AutoCompleteBox>

txtcode.ItemsSource = collection;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly you have missed this one inside the DataTemplate,

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Code}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You Should bind that textbox first

**Sample Code:**

```
  <sdk:AutoCompleteBox   Margin="105,2,40,0" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ValueMemberPath="Code" FilterMode="Contains" IsTextCompletionEnabled="True" x:Name="txtcode"  Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Top" TabIndex="1" TabNavigation="Local" >
                                <sdk:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                       <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item}" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </sdk:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </sdk:AutoCompleteBox>

    txtcode.ItemsSource = collection;
```